# Timer and JSlider with images

Tags: java, swing, timer, compiler-errors, jslider

This is part of my code and it doesn't work because it keeps on saying it cannot find the symbol in my `ActionListener`. I don't know how to make it work.

So basically what I'm trying to do is make the images from 1-8.png move depending on where the slider lands and IDK how to:

```
private static JLabel value;
private static ImageIcon image;
private static Timer timer;
private static final int delay = 2000;
private static int newDelay;
private static int i = 1;

    timer = new Timer(delay, new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // makes the image at i appear and then goes to 2 and so on until i i = 8 and will return a 1 after. Will keep on doing so                                
            value.setIcon(new ImageIcon(i + ".png"));   
            i++;

            if(i == 8) {
            i = 1;
            }
        } 
    });
    timer.start();


}


private static class SliderChange implements ChangeListener {

    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent event) {

        JSlider source = (JSlider) event.getSource();
        // while it is adjusting timer stops and gets the value of where the slider hits and the newDelay will be the new timer time. (So if they drag slider to 6, delay(which is 2000) will be divided by 6 to get new time
        if (!source.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
            timer.stop();
            value.setIcon(new ImageIcon(i + ".png"));
            newDelay = (delay/(int)source.getValue());
            timer = new Timer(newDelay, new Actionlistener());  
            timer.start();
        }

    }

}
```

But this doesn't work. How can I fix it?

It points to this line saying there is an error:

```
timer = new Timer(newDelay, new Actionlistener());
```

Comment: Not sure if you need to create a new `Timer` each time, maybe stop the current timer and simple change it's delay and restart it.  The problem is `new ActionListener())` is attempting to create an instance of a `interface` without implementing the requirements of said `interface`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure it's really necessary to recreate the `Timer` each time. Instead, stop it, set it's `delay` property and restart it instead

```
private static class SliderChange implements ChangeListener {

    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent event) {

        JSlider source = (JSlider) event.getSource();
        // while it is adjusting timer stops and gets the value of where the slider hits and the newDelay will be the new timer time. (So if they drag slider to 6, delay(which is 2000) will be divided by 6 to get new time
        if (!source.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
            timer.stop();
            value.setIcon(new ImageIcon(i + ".png"));
            newDelay = (delay/(int)source.getValue());
            timer.setDelay(newDelay);
            timer.start();
        }

    }

}
```

The problem is `timer = new Timer(newDelay, new Actionlistener());` is trying to create an instance of a `interface` without the implementing the requirements of the `interface`, which is confusing the compiler